# how to push notification from postman to firebase?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, postman

I'm Trying to push notification from postman to firebase for testing 
I posted using documentation tips and response is success but nothing sent to my android device .. I tested my code using debugging and firebase console and it working well but when i used postman nothing happens

This is my posting format

http://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

```
Content-Type : application/json
Authorization: key=AAAAitv2sYo:APA91bENlw37p5pa7pMIKoVv8CroevA7tK3tVFNGUchhGf_zkeKVFdQeYcKQmxsg-2ZOkNHMAvloRjTugmZHzNBa_TLMR2_7lffglJvrKHT1TNixHxtXZimWi2f7c16M2M7ic2S5g1gC


 {
   "notification" : 
   {
    "body" : "hello",
    "title": "firebase",
    "sound": "default"
   },
    "to" : "AAAAitv2sYo:APA91bENlw37p5pa7pMIKoVv8CroevA7tK3tVFNGUchhGf_zkeKVFdQeYcKQmxsg-2ZOkNHMAvloRjTugmZHzNBa_TLMR2_7lffglJvrKHT1TNixHxtXZimWi2f7c16M2M7ic2S5g1gC"
}
```

i used authorization and to is the same key " server key "

and the response is

```
{
    "multicast_id": 9063339683658826188,
    "success": 1,
    "failure": 0,
    "canonical_ids": 0,
    "results": [
        {
            "message_id": "0:1533133178192931%0000000000000000"
        }
    ]
}
```

> Note : When i write https posting is failed and got Could not get any
>   response error when i made it http it get the above response

another question .. can i see the sent message in firebase console ?

Comment: Only messages sent via the console are visible in it's sent logs.

Answer (score 1):

The `Authorization` key in the header and the `to` property in the message have different purposes and are never the same value.

The `Authorization` key validates your request to the Firebase server.  Its value is the "Server key" shown in the Cloud Messaging tab of your Project settings at the Firebase console.

The message `to` value is the registration ID of the device to which you are sending the message.  It is obtained from a call to a client-side SDK.

Comment: so i didn't need to if i want to send to all devices ? if i did that the same result and not working also

Comment: See Table 1 of [the documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref#downstream-http-messages-json) for options on specifying message receiver(s).  To send to a group of devices you can use a topic.  Maybe omitting `to` will cause the message to be sent to all devices, but I doubt that.

Comment: thank you .. so what's the problem in sending notification from postman ? the posting request is true but no response in Firebase or my device ?

Comment: Check that your registration ID (token) you are providing as the value of `to`. Is valid.  You can copy it into the target field when composing a message in the Firebase Console.  If the message sent from the console is not received, then the ID is not valid or there is a problem with your message receiving code on the device.

Comment: Why is should add registeration id ? i want to sent to all devices

Comment: The only way to send to all devices is to have them register to a topic and then send the message to that topic.